# apt-cache shows wrong package version available

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-cache

I'm going mad with the following issue.
I've added a PPA (ppa:savoury1/encryption) on two machines running Ubuntu 20.10.

On the first one, I see:

```
apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installato: 1.1.1j-1ubuntu0~20.10.sav0
  Candidato:  1.1.1f-1ubuntu4.3
  Tabella versione:
 *** 1.1.1j-1ubuntu0~20.10.sav0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/encryption/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.1f-1ubuntu4.3 1000
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.1f-1ubuntu4 1000
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
```

On the second:

```
apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installato: 1.1.1j-1ubuntu0~20.10.sav0
  Candidato:  1.1.1j-1ubuntu0~20.10.sav0
  Tabella versione:
 *** 1.1.1j-1ubuntu0~20.10.sav0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/encryption/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.1f-1ubuntu4.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.1f-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
```

Why is the candidate different?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` on both servers before apt-cache policy ?

Comment: @SorenA Sure I did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why is the candidate different?*

Because the priorities of the repositories are different in each system, which result in different candidate packages from different repositories. In the first system the Ubuntu repository has 1000 priority, and the PPA has 500 priority. In the second system both repositories have 500 priority.

If you want to achieve consistency between both systems you will need to change the repository priorities in one of the systems. This is done by what is called "Repository Pinning".

Comment: How to view/change them?

Comment: I never had to do this, but you can start here: https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration
Another option: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto
Whenever you have to edit a configuration file, if that file does not exist, you should just be able to create it.

Comment: I'd like to understand where I can confirm the two machines give different priorities...

Comment: From the output of `apt-cache policy openssl`, in the lines `1.1.1j-1ubuntu0~20.10.sav0 500` or `1.1.1f-1ubuntu4.3 1000`, the number at the end of the line denotes the priority for that version of the package.

Comment: found in /etc/apt/preferences.d/ folder